# How to install different package with different version in two different virtual env ubuntu18.04?

Tags: python3, virtualenv

I need to install two versions of a package in two different virtual env.
Here is what i did.

**Virtual env1**

1. Create a virtual env for env1 `python3 -m venv ./env1`
2. source ./env1/bin/activate
3. pip3 install rasa==1.4.3
   When i check rasa version `rasa --version` it shows `rasa.1.4.3

**Virtual env2**

4. Create a virtual env for env2 `python3 -m venv ./env2`
5. source ./env2/bin/activate
6. When checking rasa version `rasa --version` its shows `rasa.1.4.3`, but i didn't install anything here. Actually i want to install `rasa==1.7.3` here.

How can i do this?

Comment: Have you considered Docker for this case?

Comment: @Yaron, Nop, is it possible to achieve using  virtual environment?

Comment: Yup, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571454/virtualenv-specifing-which-packages-to-use-system-wide-vs-local